What are top and bottom copper types in KiCAD used for?
Being at very beginner level in PCB design and in KiCAD I have bene using the following F.Cu and B.Cu settings for a two layer board:

In my case, I have most of the traces on the bottom side and a few on the top side of the PCB. After I complete routing the traces except routing for the grounds, I pour copper on both bottom and top sides.
But now I noticed under the Board Editor Layers F.Cu and B.Cu can be selected as signal or power plane or mixed ect. as in the below drop down menu:

In my case, until now it seems I was using g F.Cu and B.Cu selected as "signal". I didn't pay attention to alter these.
My question is: Do selecting F.Cu and B.Cu have any impact of the result? In my case, is there something I made fundamentally incorrect?
So if I have traces in both sides(even a few in one side and most on the other side), should I select F.Cu and B.Cu as "signal"? And in what case  the layer should be selected as "power plane"? When there's no trace but only ground or power exists?

It's pretty much just a label to help you organize; as far as I know, KiCad itself doesn't do anything with it. Some add-on programs might use it for something, but I've never touched it.

This is speculation, but it's possible that KiCad plans to integrate this with DRC rules. Altium, for example, lets you define a layer as a plane layer and it will not let you place traces on it, and allows you to specify different DRC rules for different layer classes. Another feature they might end up using it for is negative gerbers on plane layers, which produces smaller gerber files with lower geometric complexity.
